# History pushState or replaceState modifies the last item in the history, not the current state / url

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate

If I understand it correctly, `history.pushState()` will add the new entry to the end of the history list and `history.replaceState()` will replace the last item in the history list.

I have a use case where I add two entries with history.pushState(), then eventually go back to the original url using `history.back()` two times or `history.go(-2)`. Now logically, I am at the same place where I started from. I want to add new entries starting from this state again. But if I do a `history.pushState()` now, it only adds to the history list as the last item after the previous two items (which can be found, if I go forward with the browser button), but it doesn't change the current url in the browser.

I don't see any method to remove some items from the history too. So, how can I achieve this use case?